# emacs: background color doesn't change when I load different themes

Tags: colors, emacs, theme

I'm using GUI Emacs. My background color remains the same no matter which custom theme I load. It may not matter, but when I load a different theme, I always get the message:

```
message [sml] sml/theme set to automatic
```

in the minibuffer. Possibly pertinent elisp is:

```
(require 'powerline)
     .
     .
     .
(setq sml/theme 'powerline)
(sml/setup)
```

I use a slightly modified version of solarized-light as my theme. In my `.emacs` file I have:

```
(load-theme 'my-solarized-light 1)
;; (set-background-color "#fffff0")   ;; not necessary because theme was customized
```

The only difference between `solarized-light` and `my-solarized-light` is that I've set the background color to #FFFFF0 instead of #FDF6E3. One problem I have is that I can't remember how I did that.

Near the top of my `.emacs` file, under `custom-set-variables`, is

```
'(custom-enabled-themes (quote (my-solarized-light)))
```

How do I make "load-theme" work correctly again?

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem.

I had modified some font settings through `describe-face` which had set values in `custom-set-faces` in my .spacemacs file.

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(org-table ((t (:background "black" :foreground "#586e75" :weight bold)))))
```

This seemed to then be applying a background colour to all themes.  Removing this customisation and restarting spacemacs solved the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem, but instead of completely removing the customisation, I only erased :background and :foreground entries. And it worked.

Comment: I had this problem also and actually somehow had 2 custom-set-faces calls in my spacemacs file :/

Answer (score 3):

If you have enabled and use [Session Saving](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html#Saving-Emacs-Sessions), it looks like the `.emacs.d/.emacs.desktop` file keeps a copy of `background-color` in this file too. Removing it was the solution for me.

Note: Modifying the `.emacs.desktop` file inside emacs while having enabled `(desktop-save-mode 1)` on your emacs session will make emacs ask you, when exiting emacs, if you really want to update `.emacs.desktop` as it has been modified externally. You want to say NO this time only as emacs will update it with its own in-memory copy, potentially with the variable `background-color` set to something you want to get rid of.

(First time poster, please be gentle :) )

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using emacs 27 on mac os. Like another answer here, I had used `M-x customize-face default` (because "Set default face" *still* doesn't work in this version for some reason), and that actually set background and foreground. I unchecked the boxes next to those, then themes started working fine again.